# Unchecked checkbox = textbox with value 0

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListView2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    int a;
    Int32.TryParse(((TextBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("BrankyTextBox")).ToString(), out a);

    if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked=false &&
         a > 0)
    {
RegisterStartupScript("alertBox2", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error');</script>");
    }
}
```

I want to when checkbox is unchecked the value of textbox must be only 0.
But this code only changes all checkbox in listview to unchecked... Have you some idea how to solve it?

Comment: `if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked=false || a > 0)` You're setting `Checked = false` instead of checking `Checked == false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could clean this up a bit while you're at it:

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < ListView2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Int32 a;
    Int32.TryParse(((TextBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("BrankyTextBox")).Text, out a);

    if (!((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked && a > 0)
    {
        RegisterStartupScript("alertBox2", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error');</script>");
    }
}
```

In other words, use the `not operator`, which is `!`, to signify an inverse test.  `myVariable == false` is equivalent to writing simply `!myVariable`.

Comment: It run, but when I give && on place || it isn´t run :/

Comment: Is it possible that the value in `BrankyTextBox` is not just a number (something that can parse cleanly to an `Int32`)?  Or that it's parsing to zero?

Comment: Look at my edit where I replaced the `.ToString()` call with `.Text`.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You had only one `=` instead of `==` for comparison.

```
if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked == false || a > 0)
{
    RegisterStartupScript("alertBox2", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error');</script>");
}
```

Comment: Yes, a have error in first post...i have OR and i must have AND

Comment: but when a give && it not run :/

Comment: It run, but when I give && on place ||  it isn´t run :/

Answer (score 1):

You assign a value of true to the checkboxes in the if statement. You need to use a double =. Like this:

```
if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked==false ||
     a > 0)
```

Comment: It run, but when I give && on place || it isn´t run :/

Comment: Do you get an error message? If not please set a breakpoint after the try parse and check if the value of a is as ecxpected.

Comment: As adition you need to change the ToString to Text: `int32.TryParse(((TextBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("BrankyTextBox")).Text, out a);`

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` is not doing what you expect

```
    if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked=false 
       || a > 0)
```

You're assigning `false` to the `Checked` property, and this statement is always `false`.
Currently, your `if` could be rewritten to be

```
if (false || a > 0)
```

Which is obviously not what you want. Add an `=` sign, making it

```
if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked == false 
      || a > 0)
```

To fix the conditional expression. Another suggestion here would be to swap the conditions, benefiting from logical short-ciruiting:

```
if (a > 0 || ((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked == false)
```

In this case, when `a > 0` is `true` the other conditions won't be evaluated resulting in (slightly!) better performance. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336755/left-to-right-expression-evaluation) for the details about short-circuiting.

Comment: It run, but when I give && on place ||  it isn´t run :/